# How to pass params in url to a backpack create form

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using backpack 3.3 on a laravel 5.5 installation.
I want to prefill two create form fields with two URL passed values.
Say you create a basic backpack crud, named Image.
Normally you can go to domain/admin/image/create to view and fill in the form.

But if I add one or two params in the url, I get a 404.
I guess I should manage the routes file (admin.php)
I tried this way:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'image/{k}/{cid}'], function()
 {
   CRUD::resource('image', 'ImageCrudController');
 });
```

but still get a 404.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a laravel constraint. You cannot do it like that. Take a look at the manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: Thank you Indra. I guess your comment should be the answer, and not just a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Almost all field types have a `default` option. So when you define them, you can specify a default. And you can always pass a GET parameter for that default. So you can have something like this in your EntityCrudController:

```
$this->crud->addField[ // Text
    'name' => 'title',
    'label' => "Title",
    'type' => 'text',
    'default'    => \Request::has('title')?\Request::has('title'):false, // default value
]);
```

You'd then be able to send you users to `yourapp/admin/entity/create?title=your+default+value` and have that default value show up in the field.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Christian. Didn't think it could be used like that. Thanks for your help (and for the entire project).

Answer (score 0):

it works for me easier

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/resultado/create?competencia=2

```
$this->crud->modifyField("competencia_id",[
              'label' => "Competencia",
              "default"=>$this->crud->request->query->get('competencia'),
              .....
```

Comment: Cannot access protected property Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel::$request